# Xamarin.Android pdf generator

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin, filestream

I have been working on `Xamarin.Android` recently. I need to use pdf generator to send a report via email.

I have been came across to the following [blog](http://pathofacoder.com/2015/09/16/how-to-generate-a-pdf-in-xamarin-android/). I do not really know what to put in the `FileStream fs = new FileStream (???????);` In addition to that, I would like to open or see that pdf on the screen.

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.IO;
using XamiTextSharpLGPL;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp;



namespace PDFAapp
{
    [Activity (Label = "PDFAapp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream (???????);
            Document document = new Document (PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance (document, fs);
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            document.Close();
            writer.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Having the following code to open the generated Pdf, but it shows pdf format is not valid.

```
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file), "application/pdf");
StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hey, did you manage to generate PDF using `ITextSharp` in Xamarin Android? I have tried using `ITextSharp` and no luck. It generates exception says cannot load assembly System.Drawing.dll. I guess it is because `ITextSharp` uses System.Drawing in it and Xamarin.Android is not (based on  [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First make sure in the  `Manifest` file you allow `WriteExternalStorage`

> In order to read or write files on the external storage, your app must
>   acquire the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE system
>   permissions. For example:

```
 <manifest ...>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 </manifest>
```

`FileStream` constructor (one of the many) accepts string for a path and `FileMode` so an example solution would be.

```
  var directory = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory, "pdf").ToString();
  if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
  {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
  }

  var path = Path.Combine(directory, "myTestFile.pdf");
  var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
```

This creates folder called "pdf" in to external storage and then creates the pdf file. Additional code could be included to check if file exists before creating it..

Edit: complete example, just tested on my device:

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            var directory = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory, "pdf").ToString();
            if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            }

            var path = Path.Combine(directory, "myTestFile.pdf");

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Delete(path);
            }

            var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            document.Close();
            writer.Close();
            fs.Close();

            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file), "application/pdf");
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Hi Milen, how could I write a text in the pdf and display it afterwards.

Comment: the blog you quoted has some basic sample how ta add text as a paragraph, to view pdf documents have a look in here: http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-open-pdf-file-in-webview.html

Comment: Milen, Is it possible to save it into the device rather than externalstorage? I do not have external storage for my testing device. Thanks a lot for the link, it is great. By the way, I believe it would be very useful if you include a sample code regarding how to open the pdf in your answer. By doing so, other SOF users will get benefit out of it.

Comment: External storage is not just your sd card, have a look in here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: Do you have permission to write external storage in your android manifest file? (see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: Yes that part was missing. Now it does not return that error any more.

Comment: Milen, sorry for bothering you again. I have added a piece of code in my question to open generated pdf, but it shows me that file is not in pdf format.

Comment: Could be the file was created previously and corrupted see my edit with checks if file exists, hope it helps :)

Comment: Milen, do you have any clue for the following question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111575/rootview-height-and-width-in-tamarin

Comment: Hey guys, did you manage to generate PDF using `ITextSharp` in Xamarin Android? I have tried using `ITextSharp` and no luck. It generates exception says cannot load assembly System.Drawing.dll. I guess it is because `ITextSharp` uses System.Drawing in it and Xamarin.Android is not (based on  [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/))

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing cross platform development its bettor to genarate PDF in commen place. please see the below code on PDF creation in PCL using iTEXT sharp.
[iTEXT PDF](http://itextpdf.com/)

here i have use PCL storage library for IO access which is very useful for PCL.
you can find more info here [PCL Storage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage)

1. Add PCL storage library to your PCL project and as well as the relevant platforms using nuget.

Install-Package PCLStorage

2. Add iTEXT PDF to your PCL project

   Install-Package iTextSharp
3. use below code in PCL project

   ```
   public class PdfHelper
   {
     public async Task PCLGenaratePdf(string path)
     {
       IFolder rootFolder = await FileSystem.Current.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
       IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("folder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
       IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("file.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

       using (var fs = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
       {
           var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
           PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
           document.Open();
           document.Add(new Paragraph("heloo everyone"));
           document.Close();
           writer.Close();
       }
    }

    public async Task<string> PCLReadFile(string path)
    {
       IFile file = await FileSystem.Current.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
       return file.Path;
    }
   }
   ```
4. use the below code in android project

TO Generate PDF

```
    private async void Genarate(string path)
    {
        var creator = new PdfHelper();
        await creator.PCLGenaratePdf(path);
    }
```

Read PDF using intent

```
    private async void ReadPDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        String sdCardPath = Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        String fullpath = Path.Combine(sdCardPath, "folder/" + "file.pdf");

        var creator = new PdfHelper();
        string filePath = await creator.PCLReadFile(fullpath);

        Uri pdfPath = Uri.FromFile(new File(filePath));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        intent.SetDataAndType(pdfPath, "application/pdf");
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

5. write ios code to generate and get PDF.

**Note**: *sometimes there can be error on system.drawings and system.security once you compile the PCL project. solution is using the iTEXT sharp source code remove all the system.drawings and system.security dependencies.*

Happy Coding.