# rootView Height and Width in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to get a screen capture in the `Xamarin.Android` platform.

```
public static Android.Content.Context Context { get; private set; }

public override View OnCreateView(View parent, string name, Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
{
    MainActivity.Context = context;
    return base.OnCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
}
```

I am trying to find out the why the following `rootView.Width` and `Height` returns 0 all the time.

```
var rootView = ((Activity)MainActivity.Context).Window.DecorView.RootView;
Console.WriteLine ("{0}x{1}", rootView.Width,rootView.Height);
```

My ultimate goal is to capture the screenshot of the view as an image and generate pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Xamarin, however it seems to be the same as native Android for this solution.

When onCreateView() is called the views have not yet been measured. To get a view dimensions you should attach a specific listener: `onLayoutChangeListener`.

Here is an Android native code example:

```
rootView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop,
        int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        int width = right - left;
        int height = bottom - top;
        v.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this); // Remove the listener
    }
});
```

You could find [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Views.View.AddOnLayoutChangeListener(Android.Views.View.IOnLayoutChangeListener)/) the listener to use for Xamarin

Hope its help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

In the onCreateView the width & height of objects are not yet defined. They are defined in a later stage of the activity's lifecycle.

You have to use the treeviewobserver for this.

Example with your rootview:

```
rootView.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
      Console.WriteLine ("{0}x{1}", rootView.Width,rootView.Height);
};
```

In that method the width & height will be known.

Furthermore, you want to take a picture of the your rootview, the best way to do this is to use this method, this will automatically output a Bitmap of the view to variable b.

```
rootView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
Bitmap b = rootView.GetDrawingCache(true);
```

Hope this gets you on your way!